# For empty value set to zero in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I try to set empty MySQL value to zero. I used IFNULL but it doesn't work. Sorry for my bad english.

```
<select name="stock_i_h_id" id="stock_i_h_id" class="form-control  m-bot15" required>
<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Item --</option>
<?php 
$ids=array();
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT IFNULL(stock_i_h_id,0) FROM other_stock_item_creation where userId='".$_SESSION['userId']."' and status_my='0'");
while($row_sid =  mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    $ids[]=$row_sid["stock_i_h_id"]; 
}
$st = implode(",",$ids);                    
$ids2=array();
$qry2 = mysql_query("SELECT IFNULL(stock_i_h_id,0) FROM dpr_stock_item where userId='".$_SESSION['userId']."' and status_my='0'");
while($row_sid2 =  mysql_fetch_assoc($qry2)){
    $ids2[]=$row_sid2["stock_i_h_id"]; 
}
$st2 = implode(",",$ids2);

$stock_item_head_name = mysql_query("select * from stock_item_head_name where userId='".$_SESSION['userId']."' and status_my='0' and id not in (".$st.",".$st2.") order by id ASC"); 
$current_date= date('d-m-Y');
while($rows_stock_item_head_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($stock_item_head_name)) 
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rows_stock_item_head_name['id'] ?>"><?php echo $rows_stock_item_head_name['stock_item_name'] ?></option required>
<?php 
}
?>
```

If `$qry` and `$qry2` returns empty value then both $st and $st2 becomes empty and then I get `NOT IN('','')` instead `NOT IN(0,0)` in the third query(`$stock_item_head_name`)

Edit:
My code works fine without `IFNULL` when both the tables `other_stock_item_creation` and `dpr_stock_item` have entries. But when the tables are empty it's not working with `IFNULL` or `IF(stock_i_h_id = '', 0, stock_i_hd)`

Comment: What is your result and what is expected result? IFNULL(stock_i_h_id,0) - this should work. Return stock_i_h_id if not null otherwise 0.

Comment: Yes, it should. But I get `''` instead.

Comment: Do you change null value to zero in status_my field?

Comment: Are you sure the values are `null` in the database? Maybe they are empty strings. That would explain your result.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is `NULL`, then `IFNULL` will definitely work. Your column must have a different value. If it is a string, this might work:

```
SELECT IF(stock_i_h_id = '', 0, stock_i_hd) ...
```

Comment: == to =  , that's sql :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
SELECT if(stock_i_h_id is null,0,stock_i_h_id ) as stock_i_h_id
```

if `stock_i_h_id`  is null return zero else the value of stock_i_h_id

Answer (score 0):

What is type of column `stock_i_h_id`? Make it DEFAULT NULL!

```
ALTER TABLE `other_stock_item_creation` change `stock_i_h_id` `stock_i_h_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL;
```

Than (if `stock_i_h_id` DEFAULT NULL):

```
UPDATE `other_stock_item_creation` set `stock_i_h_id`=NULL WHERE stock_i_h_id='';
```

And try your code.

Comment: `other_stock_item_creation` is INT(11)  Default is none.
I make it DEFAULT NULL and try the code. But with no success.

Comment: @dassoubarna and added AS to sql? SELECT IFNULL(stock_i_h_id,0) AS stock_i_h_id. May be userId empty or query match nothing? Make var_dump($query) and try query in mysql first. If it will be results than try throw php...